# JQuery: Randomly make divs fade and appear while keeping a minimum number showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of nested divs containing logos. Instead of the usual scroll to the side in either direction, I am wanting to get jQuery to first show 6 out of x logos in random.

After, 4 seconds, a random div should fade and be replaced with another, which is not currently displayed so we don't show the same logo twice. I want this to be an infinitely-lasting sequence.

I know I can use setTimer or setInterval, but my code always seems to reduce the end number to just the one. I've removed the fiddle to the most basic.

Hopefully this make sense.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//get list of divs
var div = $(".client-logos > div > div.row > div.col").toArray();
//randomly print them back out.
while(div.length > 0) {
    var idx = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50));
    var element = div.splice(idx, 1);
    $('.client-logos .column .row').append(element[0]);
    }
    $(".client-logos > div > div.row > div.col:gt(5)").hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="client-logos">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a001"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a002"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a003"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a004"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a005"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a006"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a007"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a008"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a009"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a010"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a011"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a012"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a013"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a014"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a015"></span></div>
            <div class="col"><span class="logo" id="a016"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.client-logos > div.column > div.row {
    background: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
    width: 100%;
}
div.client-logos > div.column > div.row > div.col {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 16.6667%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 16.6667%;

}
div.client-logos > div.column > div.row > div.col > span {
    align-self: center;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 20px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Fiddle URL: https://jsfiddle.net/motm/hafc7kjt/

Comment: setInterval is the start of the answer to your problem

Comment: Every interval you should fade a showing one out and fade one that isn't showing in. You can get the list of both using something like $(".col[display='none']) and it's reverse

Comment: I like how you think! I'll have to figure out how to do this!